# Android App Custom camera

Tags: android, camera

I made a custom camera and now functioning. All I want is if the user click the camera or any related that call the camera, it will appear on the screen which camera want to be used? the default camera or my custom camera, its just like that.

**example:** the latest update of My Tracks has a feature to select a camera. Now if the user click the camera icon, the choices will popup to select which camera want to be use for capturing images....any help will be appreciated...thanks

Comment: you need to register intent filters for the default camera action

Comment: Thank you SMR but another problem arises when the other application called my apps,,it will crash and phone hangs up

Answer (score 0):

As SMR mentioned put intent filter with (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) action. But it is use full if other application use this intent for image capture not its own camera implementation. Please refer [using existing camera app](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) to implement proper behavior.

Comment: thank you for the help...another problem is when my camera was called by other application like for example my tracks..the camera crash or freeze and cause the phone to hang.

Comment: refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174815/camera-crash-if-called-by-other-application